# CSS Select Images with style="float:left" possible?

Tags: css, image, css-selectors, css-float

Similar to selecting `img[title="test"]` can I somehow select images that have a style property of `float` set to `left`?

I want to set left and bottom margins for them which don't apply to right floating images.

Thank you.

Comment: What's setting them to `float: left`? Can that not also set the left and bottom margins to 0?

Comment: It's a CMS interface that's used to do that and it's a bit to complicated for some of the users to set margins. Plus the CMS interface only allows setting horiz. and vert. margins at the same time. So two by two not for each.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Peter W solution needs to be fixed like this: (changed `~=` to `*=` )

```
img[style*="float:left"] {
  margin: 5px 15px 0px 0px;
}

img[style*="float:right"] {
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

The only issue is that it makes an exact match, so `float:right` will match, while `float: right` wont (notice the extra space).

I tested successfully in Chrome and IE9, but in IE *emulation* mode will not work ...

Comment: Very helpfull thing in styling typography!

Answer (score 22):

Just to expand on this a bit, this is what I've been using for all of my images.  It catches floats as well as images that are aligned.

```
img[align="left"],
img[style*="float: left"],
img[style*="float:left"]{
    margin: 5px 15px 0px 0px;
}
img[align="right"],
img[style*="float: right"],
img[style*="float:right"]{
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

Comment: No problem. I liked the idea behind it, but it wasn't working at first. I figured others may not take as much time to debug it...

Comment: This is the best general-purpose solution, ideal for CMS systems with WYSIWYG inline images.

Comment: This can get a bit dangerous with inline styles and CSS compression (for example with Drupal's "Aggregate and compress CSS files" turned on). The space will get removed from the first rule, in essence duplicating the rule. Any inline styles that users add in the content body will not match anymore if they have a space, and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: The whitespace getting stripped out is actually a bug in Drupal's CSS compressor.  I wrote a patch for it in D7 and the D8 one is currently in progress.

Comment: Does this work for CSS coming from a stylesheet, or only inline?

Comment: I use it in stylesheets only. Never tried to inline this.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible without JS. You can put a class on the images or their parents and make a rule, though.

Comment: They are images that are placed by users through a CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
img[style~="float:left"] {
  margin: 5px 15px 0px 0px;
}

img[style~="float:right"] {
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

You can read all about CSS2 Selectors at one of these sites:

- [CSS2 attr selector examples at quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html)
- [CSS2 attr selector reference from w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-css2-971104/selector.html#h-6.3.1)

Comment: That would work if the float was not in a CSS file and in an inline style tag.

Comment: If it was in a CSS file you could edit the classes, and this issues was likely not needed.